# Error al crear base de datos POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos `POSTGRESQL` desde `Pgadmin4 Version2`.
Tengo tres escenarios distintos y no soy capaz de resolver ninguno.

**Mi primera opción.** Trato de crearla normalmente proporcionando una contraseña, incluyendo localhost y 127.0.0.1 pero me devuelve el conocido error y no crea nada:

> Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and
>   accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

**Mi segunda opcion**. Creo la base de datos con éxito si quito el checkbox "CONNECT NOW?", y sin darle el PASSWORD. Pero luego al intentar conectar no sé con qué contraseña entrar.

**Tercera opción**. Creo la base de datos con éxito si quito el `checkbox "CONNECT NOW?"`, y sin darle el PASSWORD. En este caso le indico el fichero donde está la contraseña en la última pestaña del diálogo cuando creamos la base de datos. Cuando intento conectar, me vuelve a pedir la contraseña y da el mismo error que en el primer caso.
Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Yo no he usado PostgreSQL, solamente MySQL y SQLServer. Pero parece que no tienes un servidor corriendo ya que todos los escenarios están indicando lo mismo. He encontrado esto: [Información del error](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/connect_error.html), [Conectar con un servidor](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/connect_to_server.html) Espero que te ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Revisa esta documentación: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Gracias Jose. Ojala no fuera así pero con Pgadmin4Version2 y bajo Windows, no existen los ficheros ".conf".

Comment: PgAdmin es simplemente un cliente de escritorio de Postgres. La primera vez que instalas Postgres debes configurar ciertas cosas. Ese archivo de configuración también se crea cuando instalas Postgres en Windows.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Jose. He descargado e inslatado la última versión de Postgresql para Win64 y vuelvo a tener acceso a la DB desde Pgadadmin.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Jose. He descargado e inslatado la última versión de Postgresql para Win64 y vuelvo a tener acceso a la DB desde Pgadadmin.Por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo o algo parecido describo el problema. Estoy con un proyecto y empecé por la base de datos. Todo sin problemas. Cuando integré los datos desde ficheros leídos mediante Intel Fortran a través del Visual Studio Community 2015, tuve un percance. Me equivoqué al elegir la versión del Community y elegí la 2013, tuve que desinstalar e instalar la versión 2015. Desde entonces la DB no funcionaba.Hasta hoy mismo.Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ahora, respecto a esta pregunta: ¿Estos problemas los estás sufriendo ANTES de entrar a la base de datos desde pgadmin? ¿Has probado a poner `localhost` en vez de 127.0.0.1? ¿Has comprobado que el servidor postgresql esté funcionando?

Comment: @Ceb , si has encontrado la solución por ti mismo deberías escribir una respuesta con ella y marcarla como correcta para que sepamos que el problema fue solucionado o bien borrar esta pregunta si piensas que no puede aportar nada a futuros visitantes.

Comment: hola @OscarGarcia. lo del json y php no me hace falta ya. lo de la base de datos ya lo soluciné en su dia reinstalando despues de algunos problemas con fortran y visaul studio y comparti la solucion. al menos yo puedo verla al entrar en la pregunta, no puedo borrar esa pregunta. muchas gracias por tu interes. :)

Comment: Lo del JSON, tu PHP no está identificando correctamente el contenido de los datos entregados al javascript, por eso necesitas usar el `JSON.parse()`. Si lo haces correctamente no necesitas hacerlo. Enhorabuena por lo del servidor postgresql, agrega tu solución como respuesta o borra la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Es que no estas creando una base de datos estas dando de alta un servidor, si puedes mandar una imagen de donde te estas situando para crearla seria mejor y te podria ayudar de mejor manera, pero por como se maneja postgresql lo que en realidad estas haciendo es dar de alta otro server por eso te pide ip y contraseña.

Y para crear la base de datos solo tienes que iniciar sesion como root en el grupo de servers que te da por defecto postgresql y darle en crear new DATA BASE y ya te lo crea dentro de tu server local que es tu computadora